# PHP: Fatal Error: Call to a member function winner() on null

Tags: php

I'm getting the following errors and do not know how to proceed.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ACIT4850_lab1/index.php on line
>   32
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: game­ in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ACIT4850_lab1/index.php on line
>   17
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function winner() on null in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ACIT4850_lab1/index.php on line
>   17

Here is what I have

```
<body>
    <?php
        // put your code here
        $squares = $_GET['board'];
        $game = new Game($squares);
        if ($game­->winner('x'))            // line 17
            echo 'You win. Lucky guesses!';
        else if ($game­->winner('o'))
            echo 'I win. Muahahahaha';
        else
            echo 'No winner yet, but you are losing.';
    ?>
</body>
```

and

```
 <?php
class Game {
    var $position = '---------';

    function __construct($squares) {
        $this­->position = str_split($squares);    // line 32
    }

    function winner($token) {
        $won = false;
        $result = false;

        for($row=0; $row<3; $row++) {
            if (($this->$position[3*$row] == $token) && 
                ($this->$position[3*$row+1]== $token) && 
                ($this->$position[3*$row+2] == $token))
                    $result = true;
        }
        ...

        if ($result == true)
            $won = true;

        return $won;
    }
}?>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your class game was not found.

Comment: I assume you are including the `Game` class file somewhere?

Comment: My `Game` class is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is because you have a strange char in this line

```
$this­->position = str_split($squares);    // line 32
```

the character is \u00ad

and you have all over your code like: $something\u00ad->

try with this line of code

```
$this->position = str_split($squares);    // line 32
```

aside from this you have an error in this part of the code

```
for($row=0; $row<3; $row++) {
    if (($this->$position[3*$row] == $token) &&
            ($this->$position[3*$row+1]== $token) &&
            ($this->$position[3*$row+2] == $token))
             $result = true;
```

}

you are using

```
$this->$position
```

and you need to use

```
$this->position
```

Comment: Alright, the warning on line 32 is gone. But I still have the fatal error on line 17.
And how were you able to determine that I have a strange char? I am using CodeLite and it just shows it as a space.

Comment: i pasted your code here.... https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter, because when you look the code you pasted in SO it shows no space (the char gets scaped by the browser), looks normal, but when you paste it in an IDE, it shows the whitespace, so.... i thinked something is not good and tried that...